# No top navigation bar in a tab bar controller application

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationbar, tabbarcontroller

I'm pretty new in iphone programming and have stumbled upon this issue which I guess should be pretty basic stuff.

I am using a tab bar application created from a template in XCode IOS 5.1. It works fine and creates 3 screens in the storyboard (tab bar controller + + 2 descended views) but when I try adding a top bar to these 2 views there is a problem...

I do this by adding the top navigation bar in interface builder from object inspector for the tab bar controller. After ticking this option the top bar shows perfectly in my storyboard for all 3 screens (tabbarcontroller + 2 descended views) but after I run the project the top navigation bar is no longer there.

What am I missing here? Why is there no top bar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to show a navigation bar on two `ViewControllers` of your tab bar based application, then you can do as follows:

1. Delete the viewcontroller1, then drag `ViewController` into storyboard from library and select it and go to Editor\Embed In\Navigation Controller.
2. From the `UITabBarController`, click on tabbar and right click, select relationship and drag it to the navigation controller. (means add the `UINavigationController` as a tab).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 15):

[image: By this way i integrate Navigation Bar to my viewController from tabBarController View]

follow as Nuzhat Zari to show navigation bar on viewcontrollers of your tabBar based application

Answer (score 1):

```
 self.tabBar.frame =CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,50);
```

This will make Tab Bar to appear at the top of controller.