# Elements in navigation bar don't appear using tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `Tab Bar Controller` connected to other views through a navigation controller, as I read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083521/no-top-navigation-bar-in-a-tab-bar-controller-application), in the following scheme:

```
                                        /---> NavigationController -> View1
 TableView  --->      TabBarController--|
                                        \---> NavigationController -> View2
```

The **problem** is the following: navigation bar in the View1/View2 appears with no problem, and the back button to the  first view, the TableView, works, but **elements** such as the **title**, or **buttons** in the right side of the navigation bar **aren't showed up**.

The following screenshot show my current situation.
[image]
EDIT: I have marked on the image what doesn't appear in the compiled app.

Comment: You want to display below tab bar button into view 1 & view 2?

Comment: I mean just the elements I've marked, which belong to the navigation bar (the top one). They don't appear in the compiled app.

Comment: Is your `UITabBarController`  embedded in a `UINavigationController`? I see it has a navigation bar.

Comment: @Teo. Nope, I tried but the option in Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller is disabled.

Comment: +Qubex_ anything on that?